# android ensuring safety

Tags: java, php, android

I am making app, which would send value to php script. Then php script would conncect to Mysql database and return JSON array. And then the app would read it. How to ensure safety? For now I am not using any safety measures.

Comment: safety as in when the phone drops it doesn't break?

Comment: I think he is asking how can he secure the connection.

Comment: @NiftyDude how would dropping your phone affect server side code ;p

Answer (score 1):

It depends, this is such a huge topic that a true answer would take a books worth of material.

What 'safety measures' are you asking about?

If you're talking about involving a web server, then you first need to secure your web server and build an API that is smart enough to protect against most common methods of attack. You need to make sure that other people - just by entering something in URL - cannot do the same thing your intended user can do. This means that you need to validate the user before giving them access to API.

Most common method of doing this is sharing a 'secret key' that only the server and client knows. So your user, with a phone, has a specific key and server has a key. Now user sends data to the server and also sends a validation hash (like sha1(KEY+DATA)). Server then receives data and makes sure that the hash is the same. Never send the key itself together with the request.

Another thing you need to test for are replay attacks. If someone listens in on the communication, then you have to limit the damage. This is usually done by you also sending a timestamp with the request and the server checking if the timestamp is within accepted range, so if someone sends that same request again later, it would fail due to timestamp being different. Server checks for this since timestamp is also taken into account for input data validation.

Then you have to make sure that the data returned from server is correct. So server will ALSO build a validation hash that your phone will check, making sure that someone didn't change the data while it was sent back to your phone.

As an added layer, you can also encrypt data that is sent (and received from API) with a heavy cryptography algorithm like AES/Rijndael 256bit encryption. This will encrypt data with a key that is required to open the data. If phone and server know the key and no one else does, then data can be sent securely.

Then the connection should be HTTPS/SSL, which helps protect communication from being listened in. But this does not help if someone already has access to your phone, so it is recommended to use the other mentioned methods as well.

As for your phone, it is pretty secure by itself as long as you don't have apps installed on it that might compromise that security. Also, if you think you can secure your web server less, thinking that since only phones communicate with it that it is safe, then a hacker can easily listen in on communication on their own phone and figure out the basics of your web service API and then open all the doors. So make sure your security layers go from biggest to smallest: web server is by far the biggest entity in your system.

As you can see, this is a MASSIVE topic that can take a long time to learn. But without knowing what exactly you were asking about, I cannot really help you any further.